# Give a regular expression that generates C.

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

**Question:** 
In certain programming languages, comments appear between delimiters such as /# and #/. Let C be the language of all valid delimited comment strings. A member of C must begin with /# and end with #/ but have no intervening #/. For simplicity, assume that the alphabet for C is ∑ = {a, b, /, #}.

Give a regular expression that generates C.

**My solution:**
$/\# (a\cup b \cup / \cup \#)^* \#/$

My reasoning is that it has to begin and end with /# and #/, so what is in between is irrelevant.

Is my solution valid? Thanks.

Comment: This is off topic but I have never seen a language use (in particular) the `#`. Usually it is something like: `/*` and `*/`

Comment: @Dair Neither have I, but that's how it was written in my book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Corrected version.** Your regular expression allows $/\#a\color{red}{\#/}\#/$, which is explicitly disallowed by the definition: there can be no instance of $/\#$ between the delimiters, so the red $\#/$ is not allowed. We need to ensure that no $\#/$ occurs between the delimiters. To put it a little differently, we need to ensure that if a $\#$ occurs between the delimiters, it is immediately followed by an $a$, a $b$, another interior $\#$, or the righthand delimiter.

The regular expression

$$/\#(a\cup b\cup /\cup \#a\cup \#b)^*\#/$$

almost works, but it’s too restrictive: it doesn’t allow strings of the form $/\#\#^+\#/$, for instance, or strings of the form $/\#\#^+a\#/$, all of which should be acceptable. Two small modifications fix much of the problem:

$$/\#(a\cup b\cup /\cup \#^+a\cup \#^+b)^*\#/$$

almost works, but it still misses $/\#\#\#/$ and some other legitimate strings. Can you find one more simple fix to patch this hole?

Comment: It has to end with #/ not /#. It only says  #/ is not allowed, nothing about /#.

Comment: @user283591: Thanks; fixed now.

Comment: Regarding your question, should it end with $\#^+/$ to include the following regex: /###/

Comment: @user283591: Yes, that’s probably the most efficient solution.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: The regex matches /###///#/ however there should be no intervening #/ according to the specification. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Vectorizer: No, you’re not missing anything: the OP and I both missed this error. I’ve fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

$$Regex = /\# (a\cup b\cup /\cup (\#^*(a\cup b)))^*\#/$$

Answer (score 0):

first construct an NFA to recognize the Language , construct a GNFA next , then change it to a regular expression , finally it should give:

/#(a ∪ b ∪ /)*#(# ∪ ( (a∪b)(a ∪ b ∪ /) * #) )*/

which allows all valid expression including the /# #* #/